# Non scrolling GridView

Tags: android

I want to use a `GridView` that will just expand it's height to show all it's children. The reason for this is that I want to place a custom view above the `GridView`, which should scroll along with the `GridView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <com.myapp.myview
            android:id="@+id/myview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:horizontalSpacing="@dimen/spacing_small"
            android:numColumns="2"
            android:padding="@dimen/spacing_small"
            android:verticalSpacing="@dimen/spacing_small" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Remove ScrollView, And try it

Comment: This just scrolls the `GridView`, and leaves the custom view at the top. I want the custom view to scroll along.

Comment: Putting one scrollable view (e.g. `ScrollView`, `ListView`, `GridView`, ...) inside another one is a bad idea (it is fine if each scroll in different direction). If you do it, you'll run into a lot of problems.

Comment: Therefore, my question. How can I make the GridView non-scrollable, just expanding it's height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created my own `View` which puts the children in a custom table.

Comment: How you achieved the desire result? I'm facing the same issue.